# python matrix multiplication check if number of rows of 1st matrix is equal to number of columns of 2nd matrix

Tags: python-3.x, matrix-multiplication

I need to perform a matrix multiplication between 2 matrices by taking user input. The below code works fine for the multiplication part but if the no. of rows of 1st matrix are not equal to the no. of columns of the 2nd matrix then it should print NOT POSSIBLE and exit. But it still goes on to add the elements of the matrices. What could possibly be wrong in this code & what could be the solution for the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
def p_mat(M,row_n,col_n):
    for i in range(row_n):
        for j in range(col_n):
            print(M[i][j],end=" ")
        print()


def mat_mul(A_rows,A_cols,A,B_rows,B_cols,B):

    if A_cols != B_rows:
        print("NOT POSSIBLE")

    else:
        C = [[0 for i in range(B_cols)] for j in range(A_rows)]

        for i in range(A_rows) :
            for j in range(B_cols) :
                C[i][j] = 0
                for k in range(B_rows) :
                    C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]

        p_mat(C, A_rows, B_cols)

if __name__== "__main__":


    A_rows = int(input("Enter number of rows of 1st matrix: "))
    A_cols = int(input("Enter number of columns of 1st matrix: "))
    B_rows = int(input("Enter number of rows of 2nd matrix: "))
    B_cols = int(input("Enter number of columns of 2nd matrix: "))

    ##### Initialization of matrix A and B #####

    A = [[0 for i in range(B_cols)] for j in range(A_rows)]
    B = [[0 for i in range(B_cols)] for j in range(A_rows)]





    print("Enter the elements of the 1st matrix: ")

    for i in range(A_rows):
        for j in range(A_cols):
            A[i][j] = int(input("A[" + str(i) + "][" + str(j) + "]: "))


    print("Enter the elements of the 2nd matrix: ")

    for i in range(B_rows):
        for j in range(B_cols):
            B[i][j] = int(input("B[" + str(i) + "][" + str(j) + "]:"))


    ##### Print the 1st & 2nd matrices #####

    print("First Matrix : ")
    p_mat(A,A_rows,A_cols)

    print("Second Matrix : ")
    p_mat(B,B_rows,B_cols)


    ### Function call to multiply the matrices ###

    mat_mul(A_rows,A_cols,A,B_rows,B_cols,B)
```

Comment: Use `return` to stop the function `mat_mul` or raise an exception. or terminate the program using `sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matrix multiplication, the number of columns in the first matrix must be equal to the number of rows in the second matrix.

If you want to check the no of rows of 1st matrix and the no. of columns of the 2nd matrix then change the `if A_cols != B_rows` to `if A_rows != B_cols`

With your current code, it will print `NOT POSSIBLE` when A_cols != B_rows which is right.
Ex.

```
Enter number of rows of 1st matrix: 2         
Enter number of columns of 1st matrix: 3
Enter number of rows of 2nd matrix: 2
Enter number of columns of 2nd matrix: 3
Enter the elements of the 1st matrix: 
A[0][0]: 1
A[0][1]: 2
A[0][2]: 3
A[1][0]: 4
A[1][1]: 5
A[1][2]: 6
Enter the elements of the 2nd matrix: 
B[0][0]:1
B[0][1]:2
B[0][2]:3
B[1][0]:4
B[1][1]:5
B[1][2]:6
First Matrix : 
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
Second Matrix : 
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
NOT POSSIBLE
```

Another mistake in the code is when you are initialize the Matrices.You are doing

```
A = [[0 for i in range(B_cols)] for j in range(A_rows)]
B = [[0 for i in range(B_cols)] for j in range(A_rows)]
```

If the B_cols are smaller than the A_cols when you adding elements in A it will raise IndexError
The same if the B_cols are greater than A_cols when you are adding elements to B will raise IndexError.
Change it to

```
A = [[0 for i in range(A_cols)] for j in range(A_rows)]
B = [[0 for i in range(B_cols)] for j in range(B_rows)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. It was a simple but an important error at the matrix initialization that you found. It means a lot to me. All the issues have been resolved & code's working fine. Great Explanation of the logic too. Once again thanks a ton. :)

Comment: Your welcome mate! I'm very happy that I helped! :-)